# Getting Azure AD OAuth token from ServiceNow. (SSO enabled)

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I have a requirement in ServiceNow where I need to pass the user's bearer token from ServiceNow to another application's API to get authenticated. Our ServiceNow instance has SSO with Azure AD.

It seems ServiceNow uses SAML token and so OAuth isn't available.

Is there any way, we can make a call to Azure (from ServiceNow) to get the token for the currently logged-in user and then pass it to another application for authentication.

If we can do it without Prompt then that will be great.

I tried Application Registry like below, but not sure how to use it in script (for testing I would like to try in the script background).

I am new to ServiceNow so not much familiar with it. Please help. Have been searching for this for several weeks and now fed up with less documentation. Sorry for too much "I"s.

Here is my Application Registry:
[image]